# Given a solution $y_1(x) = \cos(x)$, find the General Solution of $2y'\sin(x) + (\sin^2(x)+1)-y^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The final solution via a online calculator I found to be
$y(x) = \cfrac{1}{C \csc(x) - \frac 12x\csc(x)}+\cos(x),\:$ where $C$ is a constant

I struggle to get to this solution however.
Now I know this is a Ricatti DE as a particular solution is given so this is the work I've done thus far:

Get $y'$ by itself

so $y' = \cfrac{y^2-(\sin^2(x)+1)}{2\sin(x)}$

Now using the substitution $y = y_1 + \frac 1v = \cos(x) + \frac 1v$

$y' = -\sin(x) - \cfrac {1}{v^2}v' $

Setting the $y's$ equal to one another we get

$\cfrac {y^2-(\sin^2(x)+1)}{2\sin(x)} = -\sin(x) - \cfrac{1}{v^2}v'$

Making the substitution for $y$ we get

$\cfrac{(\cos(x) + \frac 1v)^2 - (\sin^2x+1)}{2\sin(x)} = -\sin(x) - \cfrac{1}{v^2}v'$

Here I have no idea where to go from as getting v' by itself results in a absolute nightmare.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to take the intermediate steps first, that is, first use the offset towards the given solution directly. Set $y=y_1+u$, then the DE reads as, $y_1$ being a solution,
$\newcommand{\b}[1]{\color{blue}{#1}}$
$$
0=2\sin(x)(\b{y_1'}+u')+\b{\sin^2(x)+1}-(\b{y_1^2}+2y_1u+u^2)
\\
=2\sin(x)u'(x)-2y_1(x)u(x)-u(x)^2
$$
This now is a Bernoulli equation where indeed setting $u=\frac1v$ leads to a linear equation
$$
0=-2\sin(x)v'(x)-2\cos(x)v(x)-1
\\
0=2(\sin(x)v(x))'+1
$$
etc.

Comment: I don't understand what happened after the first line, could you explain, where is the $\sin^2(x)$ gone ?

Comment: I've marked the terms in blue that cancel due to $y_1$ being a solution. One could also just insert $y_1=\cos(x)$ to the same effect.

Comment: Yes since the cosecant function is just $1/\sin x$ @TotomaLover2312

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks! Just a quick question. Why does the substitution $y =y_1 + u$ work? My textbook says that we should use the substitution $y = y_1 + \frac 1v$ and I see that you eventually use $\frac 1v$ in the Bernoulli part, but I'm not sure why we should use $y = y_1 +u$ and why this works. where does this come from? And why does this work?

Comment: If you have two solutions of $y'=ay^2+by+c$, then in the difference of their equations you get $y_2'-y_1'=(y_2-y_1)(a(y_2+y_1)+b)$ which strongly suggests to find the equation for the difference $u=y_2-y_1$, eliminating $y_2$. It just works in this special case. Luckily enough this special case also covers some DE from "real" situations.

Comment: Oh thanks. I figured that this was just a special case. I just need to look for that pattern then. Thanks for your help!